# SQL Return from list of strings via boolean

Tags: sql

I have information that I am trying to report on that is currently categorized via a vlookup table in excel. This table would check the data coming from my `days_past_due` column in SQL database and return a string.

**I.E.** `days_past_due = 5` would return the string '5-10 Days Past due'

I have about 8 different number ranges that would get their own string. Is their a way to hardcode this into the SQL query?

It is worth mentioning the string data is NOT in my database.

Comment: `case` / `when`.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `case` statement. Basically you can tell the query to return a specific value based on a condition.  Can you post the actual sql query? Use this as a guide: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: Just use CASE and BETWEEN statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CASE function to achieve this.

```
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN days_past_due = 5 THEN '5-10 Days Past due'
    WHEN ......
    ELSE <returndefaultcase>
    END
  FROM <tablename>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CASE logic to get this.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN days_past_due = 5 THEN '5-10 Days Past due'
            WHEN ...
       END 
FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I had a complete brain fade when I was researching the question yesterday. I was about to post this answer myself this morning.